# A better way to generate this json array from MySql data with php

Tags: php, mysql

Sql fiddle for your convenience [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0093a).

I'm taking data from a MySql table and turning it into a json array. All works well and I have the output the way I want it, but is there a way this can be improved (shortened/improved)? The array keys have to remain the same and need to match the dbs output.

**My Code**

```
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("select name as name, age as age, address as address, pincode as pincode from json where name = 'peter'");
    $stmt->execute();

    while( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) {
        #echo $row['name']." ".$row['age']." ".$row['address']." ".$row['pincode'].'<br>';
        $myarray['name'] = $row['name'];
        $myarray['age'] = $row['age'];
        $myarray['address'] = $row['address'];
        $myarray['pincode'] = $row['pincode'];
    }

    echo json_encode($myarray);
```

**My Output (the above code successfully outputs this)**

```
{"name":"Peter","age":"30","address":"1 Elm Street","pincode":"91550"}
```

Comment: Is the name unique? And why do you do "name as name" since it is not needed

Comment: Name is unique. I'll be using `where name = 'myName'`

Answer (score 2):

Taking out all the redundancy, using proper prepared statements (assuming PDO) and adding error handling (at least a stub), you end up with this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT name, age, address, pincode FROM json WHERE name = ?');
$stmt->execute(array('peter'));

if ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo json_encode($row);
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error'));
}
```

If you expect multiple rows:

```
echo json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Answer (score 2):

You only select needed fields, so you can just do

```
echo json_encode($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

EDIT: You mention now that name is unique, so above is all you need.

Comment: You shouldn't `while` if you only expect one row.

Comment: name is not unique is my guess. Think this is the best solution, combined with the better prepare suggested by you

Comment: `name = 'peter'` may not be unique, that's why I kept the `while`. If `name` is unique, you are of course right.

Comment: If you *do* expect multiple rows this will corrupt your JSON output.

Comment: In the original script, each loop overwrites the content, hence only one line is echo'ed anyway. Without knowing the purpose of the script I will try to change as little as possible. The echo may just be for test, I don't know.

Comment: The OP obviously doesn't know what's best, don't suggest equally non-correct code. :)

Comment: I dont. I'll be using `where name='peter' and id='10`` lter on.

Comment: Why does this give me [ ] at the beginning and end of the json array?

Comment: It shouldn't... But you mention `name` is unique, wo all you need is the line I edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($row);
```

You don't need the while loop, if you only have one row in your result.